# "Invariant Violation" Using React Server renderToString on Server-Side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to set up an isomorphic server-side rendering React app using Webpack, but am getting this error when I try turning my React code into a string using renderToString:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

I stop getting this error when I comment out the line with the renderToString function (of course, the app still doesn't work - I just no longer get an error message).

I've tried passing renderToString `<RootApp />` and `React.createElement(RoutingContext` instead of making a factory, and neither of those has worked. Using `React.createElement` resulted in the same error, and using `<RootApp />` threw an `unexpected token < error`.

And ideas on what could be going on?

My app looks like:

app.js

```
"use strict"

require("babel-register");
const Express = require('express');
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Path = require('path');
const Fs = require('fs');
const Url = require('url');
const ReactRouter = require('react-router');
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

const app = Express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  let RootApp = require('./components/app.jsx');
  let rootAppFactory = React.createFactory(RootApp);
  let reactHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(rootAppFactory({}));
  res.render('index', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
})

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  let port = process.env.port || 4000;
  app.listen(port);
  console.log('Listening on port', port);
} else {
  module.exports = app;
}
```

app.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Vjeverica</title>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <%- reactOutput %>
    </div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up getting this working. The issue was in how I was requiring app.jsx in app.js - because I'm using `require` instead of `import`, I needed to change `require('./components/app.jsx')` to `require('./components/app.jsx').default` to get the default export.